# Objective C to Swift interoperability issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a curious case where I have the following Objective C protocol:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@protocol AccountCriteria <NSObject>
- (BOOL)criteriaIsApplicableForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (nullable id <ModularFactory>)criteriaMetForAccount:(Account *)account error:(NSError **)error NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

To which I have decided to have a Swift class implement the protocol, like so:

```
import Foundation

@objc(PaymentCriteria)
public class PaymentCriteria: NSObject, AccountCriteria {

    public func criteriaIsApplicable(forIdentifier identifier: String) -> Bool {
        //Lots of code here
    }

    public func criteriaMet(for account: Account, error: NSErrorPointer) -> ModularFactory? {

        //Lots of code here
    }

}
```

The intention is to use the `PaymentCriteria` class in other Objective C code. However with this particular code I keep getting a `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue`.  Now if I remove the `public` from the class everything builds fine. However, I can't use `PaymentCriteria` in any Objective C code.

If I keep the class as public but remove `AccountCriteria` from the class, everything still builds fine. However, I have to have this class abide by the protocol. So this route doesn't help me very much as well.

So my question is, why can't I have a Swift class abide by an Objective C protocol and then try and use that Swift class in Objective C? Or is there something pernicious that I'm doing wrong in the Swift class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, the issue here with let's call it, **cyclic importing**.

So, You've created Objc protocol, then add this Objc file to Bridging header. It is being imported to all swift files, including your `PaymentCriteria.swift` file.
Then you try using `PaymentCriteria` back in objc, which leads to adding it to umbrella header. And generally because of such a path I experienced similar errors.

The simplest workaround would be creation AccountCriteria as a protocol using Swift with `@objc`.